Proving that two languages both represent valid bracket sequences
I have two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, both subsets of $\{0, 1\}^*$, defined as follows:
For $L_1$, we have that

$01 \in L$
If $w \in L$, then $0w1 \in L$
If $w_1, w_2 \in L$, then $w_1w_2 \in L$

For $L_2$, we have that

$01 \in L_2$
If $w \in L_2$, then if $w_1w_2 = w$, then $w_101w_2 \in L_2$ as well

I am trying to show that both of these languages are equivalent; that $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ and vice versa.
I've thought for a while, and the best idea I've had is that both $L_1$ and $L_2$ seem to contain all valid bracket sequences. That is, the strings in $L_1$ and $L_2$ are exactly the strings where

For any prefix of the string, the number of $0$s is $\geq$ than the number of $1$s
The total number of $0$s is equal to the total number of $1$s

However, when I try to show that every string in $L_1$ is also in $L_2$ via structural induction, I get stuck. For instance, if I suppose that $w \in L_1$ and I want to show that $0w1 \in L_2$, I am unable to see how to decompose $0w1$ into the rules specified by $L_2$.
Can someone provide a solution to this problem or give me some hints?

Prove by induction that if $w\in L_2$ then $0w1 \in L_2$.

Case $w = 01$, we want to prove $0w1 \in L_2$. Indeed, we start with $01 \in L_2$, and then use the second rule with $w_1 = 0$, $w_2 = 1$. Therefore $w_101w_2 = 0011 = 0w1 \in L_2$.

Case $w = w_101w_2$. The induction hypothesis is $0w_1w_21 \in L_2$. We split $0w_1w_21 \in L_2$ into $w_1' = 0w_1$ and $w_2' = w_21$, and we insert $01$ in the middle. Therefore $0w_101w_21 = 0w1 \in L_2$.



Sorry, can you elaborate? I tried using structural induction on $w$ ($w = w_101w_2$ where $w_1w_2$ is given to be in $L_2$), but I can't see how to prove that the string achieved from stripping the 0 and 1 from the beginning and end of $w_101w_2$ is always in $L_2$.

I edited a proof in.
